# Parallel two TPS2115A to get a higher current output

Tags: power

Can i parallel two TPS2115A devices to get higher current output. 
A single TPS2115A power mux can only switch 2A max load. My requirement is to switch 3A load.

As per the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2115a.pdf), the device has a REVERSE-CONDUCTIONBLOCKING mode. Will it prevent current OUT form one device getting in to other output.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this, the problem is if you did, a way would be needed to make sure you don't send more than 2A through one TPS2215A. The other problem is matching between devices, if one device has say 10% more resistance, then the other device would conduct more current and dissipate more heat.

But TI also has a [TPS2120](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS2120/description) that is rated for 3A which would be an easier solution.

Comment: It seems that it might be difficult to parallel the two devices. TPS2120 current rating is OK but it is very difficult to hand solder the BGA package.